# Custom AppBar Button from image with C# in Windows 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How can we use png image file in an AppBar button **that handle visual states** (When using a simple white image in a appbar button, it just doesn't support visual state). 
It seems possible when using HTML/JS, but I didn't find any equivalent in XAML/C#.

Here is my attempt :

Full of hope, I followed HTML/JS instructions, so I created a 160x80 px image, with scale suffix (filename : "myimage.scale-100.png"). This image is composed with multiple 40x40 px sprites, each representing a specific visual state.
In my XAML code:

```
 <Button x:Name="Btn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" >
     <Button.Content>
         <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/myimage.png" />
     </Button.Content>
 </Button>
```

The image appears, but as a normal images (all sprites are visible).

edit :

The sprite image (background color for debug purpose)

[image: The sprite image (background color for debug purpose)]

As it appear in the application (in the bottom bar) :

[image]

Comment: Can you post the images?

Comment: I think you will need to use multiple images, and change the `Source` property on each state to point each one to a different source image.